# how to filter out lines in text file with substring

Tags: python, string

I have a text file with contents like this:

```
ADUMMY ADDRESS1
BDUMMY MEMBER
AA1400 EL DORA RD
BCARLOS
A509 W CARDINAL AVE
BJASMINE
```

I want a python script to count the number of lines that begin with "B" but do not contain the substring "DUMMY".

Here is what I have so far but I dont know how to do the filter in the "if" statement.

```
def countLinesMD(folder,f):
    file = open(folder+f,"r")
    Counter = 0

    # Reading from file
    Content = file.read()
    CoList = Content.split("\n")

    for i in CoList:
        if i.startswith("B"):
            Counter += 1
return Counter
```

Comment: `Counter = sum(1 for line in CoList if line.startswith('B') and 'DUMMY' not in line)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just do this
`if i.startswith("B") and "DUMMY" not in i:`

Comment: wow that was easier than I thought. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to the `if` statement:

```
def countLinesMD(folder,f):
    file = open(folder+f,"r")
    Counter = 0

    # Reading from file
    Content = file.read()
    CoList = Content.split("\n")

    for i in CoList:
        if i.startswith("B") and "DUMMY" not in i.split():
            Counter += 1
return Counter
```